# How to determine whether a number can be expressed as a sum of factorials

Tags: summation, factorial

I'm looking for a way to determine (without calculating) whether a positive integer ***N*** can be written as the sum of factorials of random numbers where a number cannot be used more than once. For instance, $$7 = 1! + 3! = 0! + 3!$$ $$or,$$ $$6 = 3!$$ But we can't write **5** or **11** in such a way. So I'm now looking for a way to know whether a given number can be written in such a way without calculating. If there is, then how?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy algorithm for it, but I would (and I probably will) write down the first handful of numbers that *cannot* be written in such a way and then search on OEIS.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of OEIS. :) @Lovsovs

Comment: See OEIS sequence A059590 (except that sequence does not count 0! and 1! as distinct factorials, so it omits 4, 10, 28 etc.). Since factorials grow so quickly a greedy algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) will always work.

Comment: $$5=0!+1!+0!+2!$$

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art: Please read the 1st line carefully. No numbers can't be used more than once. Else we can write any number in such a way: $$5 = 0! + 0! + 0! + 0! + 0!$$ :) Thank you

Comment: Ah!  I see!...  :-)